# Hyperref link spanning a pagebreak links footnote even with \DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1}

Tags: hyperref, header-footer, footnotes, page-breaking, hyperlink

It seemed to be an open problem for quite some time that hyperref link spanning a pagebreak also hyperlinks headers, footers and footnotes inbetween ([Hyperref Link Spans a Pagebreak, Looks Ugly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54136/hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly), [page break in the middle of a \cite](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172508/page-break-in-the-middle-of-a-cite/179907#179907), [Very long footnotes with hyperlinked text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665970/very-long-footnotes-with-hyperlinked-text), [How do I forbid pagebreaks inside urls without forbidding linebreaks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/578373/how-do-i-forbid-pagebreaks-inside-urls-without-forbidding-linebreaks/578405?noredirect=1#comment1743325_578405)).

But recetnly a very promesing solution was proposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578405/128042. If I don't misunderstand this solution simply adding the line `\DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1}` in the beginning should solve the problem for TeXLive 2022 and 2023, but when I added this line my fotnote is still hyperlinked wrongly :(

```
\DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1}
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{color}
%\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

A\footnote{AaAaAa}

B

C\label{c}

\vspace{410pt}

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \hyperref[c]{Ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc cccccccc cccccccccccc cccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccc }
\end{document}
```

Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: ah, footnote not footer. That is a different problem, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671759/2388