# Hyperref: log hyperlinks which breaks over pages. Code working for standard bibliography but not for biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref

**Is there a standard solution to log broken hyperlinks over 2 pages?** I do not want/prefer them in my document, and it would be nice if I get them outputted to the log, so I can grep on it, instead of visual inspecting complete documents.

For normal Latex bibliography, I created a **hyperlink-broken-over-different-pages detector (see first MWE)** based on [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54136/hyperref-link-spans-a-pagebreak-looks-ugly).

However the **biblatex** variant (see second MWE) is not working. **Why not?**

**@Heiko:** Can we get this functionality default in hyperref? So in case you run verbose/debug you get for page breaking links a comment like "[broken over 2 pages]"??

**Working MWE:**

This gives expected output:

> HYPERLINK BREAK PAGES
>
> cite
>
> cite.reference LongSurnameOfTheFirstAuthor and
>   LongSurnameOfTheSecondAuthor, 2004
>
> HYPERLINK BREAK PAGES
>
> *Package hyperref Info: Reference (cite) `cite.reference' on input line 64.*

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=10mm,vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cite}     % numeric citations
\usepackage[debug]{hyperref} % links in PDF
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % fancy headers and footers

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the sake of this example

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{lnkpg}
\renewcommand*{\thelnkpg}{lnkpg\the\value{lnkpg}}
\newcommand*{\org@hyper@link@}{}
\let\org@hyper@link@\hyper@link@
\protected\def\hyper@link@[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \def\lnkpg@callorg{%
    \org@hyper@link@[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{lnkpg}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg a}{abspage}%
  \zref@refused{\thelnkpg a}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{\thelnkpg a}{%
    \lnkpg@callorg
    \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
  }{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{\thelnkpg b}{%
      \mbox{\lnkpg@callorg}%
    }{%
      \edef\lnkpg@a{\zref@extractdefault{\thelnkpg a}{abspage}{0}}%
      \edef\lnkpg@b{\zref@extractdefault{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}{0}}%
      \ifx\lnkpg@a\lnkpg@b
        \wlog{>> HYPERLINK NOT BREAKING PAGES}
        \wlog{#1}
        \wlog{#2}
        \wlog{#3}
        \wlog{#4}
        \wlog{<< HYPERLINK NOT BREAKING PAGES}
        \lnkpg@callorg
        \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
      \else
        \wlog{>> HYPERLINK BREAKING PAGES}
        \wlog{#1}
        \wlog{#2}
        \wlog{#3}
        \wlog{#4}
        \wlog{<< HYPERLINK BREAKING PAGES}
        \lnkpg@callorg
        \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
       \fi
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother   
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[4]
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff
\cite{reference}
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff

\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem[LongSurnameOfTheFirstAuthor and LongSurnameOfTheSecondAuthor,
  2004]{reference}
LongSurnameOfTheFirstAuthor, D. and LongSurnameOfTheSecondAuthor, R. (2004).
\newblock Example text.
\newblock {\em Journal of example articles}, 21(12):2326--2339.
\newblock [DOI:\href{http://www.example.com}{example}].
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**MWE NOT Working based on Biblatex:**

When I switch to Biblatex, this solution is not working anymore. I expect now "HYPERLINK NOT BREAKING PAGES", because only the year is hyperlinked which does not break over pages. However I get nothing:

> Package hyperref Info: Anchor 'page.2' on input line 83. [2
>
> Package hyperref Info: End of reference (cite) `cite.0@reference', line 78.
>
> ]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{reference,
    author={LongSurnameOfTheFirstAuthor and LongSurnameOfTheSecondAuthor},
    title = {Journal of example articles},
    year = {2004}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper,hmargin=10mm,vmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,hyperref=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[debug]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % fancy headers and footers

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the sake of this example

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\thepage}}}
\fancyfoot{}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\usepackage{zref-abspage}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{lnkpg}
\renewcommand*{\thelnkpg}{lnkpg\the\value{lnkpg}}
\newcommand*{\org@hyper@link@}{}
\let\org@hyper@link@\hyper@link@
\protected\def\hyper@link@[#1]#2#3#4{%
  \def\lnkpg@callorg{%
    \org@hyper@link@[{#1}]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
  }%
  \stepcounter{lnkpg}%
  \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg a}{abspage}%
  \zref@refused{\thelnkpg a}%
  \zref@ifrefundefined{\thelnkpg a}{%
    \lnkpg@callorg
    \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
  }{%
    \zref@ifrefundefined{\thelnkpg b}{%
      \mbox{\lnkpg@callorg}%
    }{%
      \edef\lnkpg@a{\zref@extractdefault{\thelnkpg a}{abspage}{0}}%
      \edef\lnkpg@b{\zref@extractdefault{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}{0}}%
      \ifx\lnkpg@a\lnkpg@b
        \wlog{>> HYPERLINK NOT BREAKINNG PAGES}
        \wlog{#1}
        \wlog{#2}
        \wlog{#3}
        \wlog{#4}
        \wlog{<< HYPERLINK NOT BREAKING PAGES}
        \lnkpg@callorg
        \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
      \else
        \wlog{>> HYPERLINK BREAKING PAGES}
        \wlog{#1}
        \wlog{#2}
        \wlog{#3}
        \wlog{#4}
        \wlog{<< HYPERLINK BREAKING PAGES}
        \lnkpg@callorg
        \zref@labelbyprops{\thelnkpg b}{abspage}%
       \fi
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[2]\lipsum[4]
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff
\textcite{reference}
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff
Stuff stuff stuff
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: biblatex uses `\hyper@natlinkend .... \hyper@natlinkend` for the link, so you would have to hack these (or `\blx@bibhyperref`).

Comment: How do I do this?